# remove spaces from pandas column if there are 2 or 3

Tags: python, pandas

I have:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2],'col1':['a b c','a b c d']})
```

I want:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2],'col1':['ab c', 'a bc','ab cd']})
```

- there will always be 1,2 or 3 spaces in a column
- if there are 2 spaces (3 words), I want to duplicate the row, and alter the value to show `word1word2 word3` in one row, and see `word1 word2word3` in the second row
- if there are 3 words (4 spaces), I want to alter the value to `word1word2 word3word4`

I have ~ 30 columns, and test for number of spaces with

```
df['name_cnt'] = df['name'].str.count('\s+')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a function to process each value depending on its length and apply it to column `name`.
2. If the value has 3 words, the function will return a list that will later need to be exploded into more rows.

```
def process_col(col):
    w = col.split()
    if len(w) == 3:
        return [f"{w[0]}{w[1]} {w[2]}", f"{w[0]} {w[1]}{w[2]}"]
    elif len(w) == 4:
        return f"{w[0]}{w[1]} {w[2]}{w[3]}"
    else:
        return col


df["name"] = df["name"].apply(process_col)
df = df.explode("name").reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

Assuming this dataframe as input:

```
   id     name
0   1    a b c
1   2  a b c d
```

Result will be:

```
   id   name
0   1   ab c
1   1   a bc
2   2  ab cd
```